# I cant make a request or curl to a website using python 3

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests, monitoring, wget

sorry if my english is not very good, im trying to make a curl or request to a website (https://consultasislac.segob.gob.mx/csislac/init.do), but unfortunately, even in my web browser (i use google chrome) i can't access to the website, but when i use an old browser, for example Mozilla Firefox ver 8.0, i can access without problems.

I´m trying to make a curl to the website, for just get the http status code. but i get the next Error Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1092, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 783, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 470, in increment
    raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\util.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1092, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 783, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    r = requests.get(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Itoc91\Development\python\curl_url\env\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

Can anyone help me?

Greetings

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]